# index a moving range

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am trying to grab the max for each year in my dataset. The data is in one column, in order at a daily timestep.
How do I get the max from the first 365 rows, then from the next 365 rows?
I was thinking something like:

```
years=31;
for i=1:years
peak(i)=max(data(i:365*i,2))
end
```

but when i=2, the range should be from 366:730 and so forth.
The data matrix is 11322x7 double and I need column 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about suggesting something like @Thilo's answer, but that doesn't take into account leap years (which appear to show up in your data, since 365*31=11315, which is less than 11322)

You might be able to gin up a complicated vectorized solution, but I'd be tempted to just manually keep track of the start and stop indices:

```
NYEARS = 31;

start = 1;
stop = 365 + isLeapYear(year(1));
n=1;
maxValues = nan(NYEARS,1);
while(n=<NYEARS)
  maxValues(n) = max(data(start:stop,2));
  n=n+1;
  start = stop + 1;
  stop = start + 365 + isLeapYear(year(n));
end
```

It's probably not blazingly fast, but I doubt this is going to be a bottleneck either.

```
function leap_p = isLeapYear(year)
  leap_p = ~mod(year,400) || (~mod(year,4) && mod(year,100)) 
end
```

Comment: what is `isLeapYear`? my system doesn't recognize that function

Comment: Oh, totally forgot about leap years. Good thought!

Comment: Hmm, not sure where that function came from then. It's pretty simple though (see edit)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe your solution requires a couple changes.  `isLeapYear(year(1))` is a bit easier to understand as `isLeapYear(year1)` where year1 is specified  and `while(n<=NYEARS)` instead of `while(n=<NYEARS)` and `stop = start + 365 + isLeapYear(year(n));` should have a `- 1`.  Lastly, i'm gettig a "Index exceeds matrix dimensions error". thoughts?

Comment: 1) Sure; it depends on what your data looks like. If you've got an array of years, year(n) should work. Otherwise (year1 + n - 1) works too.
2) Yup. That's a typo. It's <=, not =<. Sorry--it's 2am my time :-)
3) Wrong starting year maybe? That could get you off by one or two, depending on the interval. Or could the matrix be flipped (Nx7 vs 7xN)? Maybe just print out the indices and see if anything looks bizarre.

Comment: SO I ended up with `stop =start +365 -1+isLeapYear(year1+n)`  with `n=n+1` at the end of the while loop. `year(n)` given a vector `year` of years in the dataset will go out of bounds on the last loop because `n` increases past your bounds. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Update including leap years

I doubt it matters for the amount of data you have, but I think I came up with a solution including leap years and not using any loops. Thus, for the sake of completeness. We will build the idea up again with a mini-example where a leap year has 11 days, a normal year 10.

```
data = 1:103
isLeapYear = [false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, false]
```

That vector you should replace with a result of the isLeapYear-function for all years.

Next, we generate a matrix containing 11 (or, in real life 366) rows and the number of years columns, containing only the value 1:

```
helpmatrix = ones(11, 10)
```

and set the last row of the matrix to 0 if the corresponding year is not a leap year:

```
helpmatrix(end, ~isLeapYear) = 0
```

Let's write the matrix as a vector (using reshape as described below) and sum up all the ones

```
selector = cumsum(reshape(helpmatrix, prod(size(helpmatrix)), 1))
```

Those values we can use to blow up our original data in a way that each year has 11 (366) days and we could use the trick below. To fill up the value of day 11 we just reuse the value of day 10, this does neither change the maximum not the minimum value. (But be aware: Other functions might as well be affected by this!)

```
max(reshape(data(selector), 11, length(selector)/11))
```

To transform this you would just have to exchange all the 10 and 11's by 365 and 366 and to alter the last command using `data(selector, 2)` instead of `data(selector)`.

Probably this is not much of a gain compared to the loop solution, but it shows the power of vector computations.

---

### Old suggestion

You can do that on a much simpler basis.

The function `reshape` allows you to transform a vector (or a matrix, if necessary) into another row/column-layout.

Your problem then could be solved by

```
max(reshape(data(:,2), 365, length(data)/365))
```

To understand what is happening I created a smaller example:

```
data = 1:100
reshape(data, 10, length(data)/10)
max(reshape(data', 10, length(data')/10))
```

Your loop above would also work, but inefficient. You would have to take care of how your indices are created. You do `i:365*i`. In my example above this looks like

```
for i=1:10
    i:10*i
end
```

which is clearly not what you want. Done the right way you could do

```
for i=1:10
    (10*(i-1) + 1):10*i
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: that's pretty great. sort of like a pivot table but you can actually understand whats going on! Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Krause brings up an good point about leap years.  I would have gotten confused about the output eventually.

Comment: @Dominik for the sake of completeness, I added a way to accommodate leap years in my solution.